# Lubuntu 19.04: How to add a shutdown button to taskbar? (Instead of having to go through the application menu)

Tags: lubuntu

I would like to be able to shutdown without opening the application menu.

Comment: You could try the option in this resource to use Ctrl-Alt-Del: https://vitux.com/use-ctrlaltdel-shortcut-for-shutting-down-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5):

Open pcmanfm-qt to */usr/share/applications*.

Scroll down till you see the item "Shutdown".

Drag the Shutdown icon to the quicklaunch area of your panel. Ensure you see a little green circle with a + sign before you release the icon onto the quicklaunch area.

[image]

Now, if you left-click on the Shutdown icon in the quicklaunch tray, you'll see the shutdown option.

[image]

Comment: Worked fine.  Thank you !